# An extra blank space occurs before the step XML

Tags: xml

```
<step xml:id="test_middleware_step">
            <para>Test the middleware from outside of DevStack on
                a remote machine that has access to your DevStack
                instance.</para>
            <substeps>
                <step>
           <para>Install the Keystone and Swift clients on your local machine.</para>
                    <screen><prompt>#</prompt> <userinput>pip install python-keystoneclient python-swiftclient</userinput></screen></step>
<step><para>Attempt to list the objects in the middleware-test container.</para>
<screen><prompt>$</prompt> <userinput>swift --os-auth-url=http://my.instance.ip.address:5000/v2.0/ --os-region-name=RegionOne --os-username=demo:demo --os-password=devstack list middleware-test</userinput>
<computeroutput>
Container GET failed: http://my.instance.ip.address:8080/v1/AUTH_.../middleware-test?format=json 403 Forbidden   You shall not pass!</computeroutput></screen></step>
        </substeps></step>
```

This is my code: If I don't use the `<step xml:id="">` it works OK without the blank space before that step.

But when id is used there occurs a blank space, any idea why that comes up?

Comment: Without knowing what's consuming that XML, this is impossible to answer. This is an issue with the tool, not with XML itself.

Comment: Yes, its' an issue with the tool. Didn't get that at first. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I did an edit like this and it worked.

```
<step>
           <para xml:id="test_middleware_step">
```

Gave the xml:id inside para and the extra space got removed.